# Is there really no way to know anything about any info of another website in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

We know that, for security reason, we cannot access the content of a different website in an iframe by using javascript.

But for some reason, I really need to know which website is loaded in an iframe so that I can react with a certain javascript code I wrote.

So I'm thinking that, if there is a way for me to know what files my browser just requested/loaded after loading the iframe, I would be able to guess which website is being loaded in the iframe. I already know several possible websites the iframe can load so it's not hard for me to guess the answer correctly.

For example, after loading the iframe, if I can know that my browser just requested/loaded an image whose url is `https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png`, then I'm able to know that it is Google's homepage.

Another example is that, after loading the iframe, if I can know that my browser just requested/loaded a js file whose url is `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js`, then I'm able to know that the website is the one that uses reCaptcha.

Is that possible? Or are there better solutions?

Comment: "*I would be able to guess which website is being loaded in the iframe.*" - aren't you the one who did put the iframe on your page in the first place? You should know what website you are loading. If it's dynamic, you still can inspect the `src` attribute of the iframe.

Comment: What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? What is that "*for some reason*"?

Comment: @Bergi I know the original url of the websit in the iframe. But the problem is that the original website will do a redirection to a different website. And I need to know the url of that different website.

Comment: What service is doing the redirection and why are you using it?

Comment: @Bergi The website inside the iframe will evaluate visitors' conditions (by using its own methods). If it thinks a visitor is likely to be a bot, it redirects the visitor to a captcha page.

Comment: And why does *your* website need to know whether the other website thinks that the visitor is a bot? That's exactly the kind of information the SOP is trying to protect. If the other website is providing a bot-detection *service* for arbitrary websites and is intended to be used inside a frame, there will be an API for this - look into the service's documentation.

Comment: My website uses that website's service so I need to know the said info for my visitors. I guess there is no solution then.

Comment: Ask the service provider, if they do encourage this usage then there exist solutions for *cooperating* websites (notably, cross-frame messaging).